# How to sort an HashMap using filterable.I need to get a list associate with my key search strings

Tags: java, android

I having List data inside HashMap. i need to show the List on ListView.
i added AddTextChangeListener to my editText on top of ListView. I need to filter the List according to my Search string. How i can add filter to my HashMap List?

Comment: post your code where you are stuck..

Comment: And *state* where you are stuck. I don't see any sorting in the code you've posted.